# Angular website Mobile browser page speed

Tags: angular, pagespeed

We have spent many hours trying to solve this problem. Any help will be highly appreciated! We have built the application using Angular. The desktop page speed score is around 74 but the mobile is around 23. Can someone please help? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Performance Optimization for Angular based mobile app:**

https://walkingtree.tech/performance-optimization-angular-based-mobile-app/ and
https://medium.com/swlh/angular-performance-optimization-techniques-5b7ca0808f8b

Both links will provide you with different optimization techniques that will drastically improve your application speed.

Answer (score 0):

The site takes more time in painting.

You might want to try implementing lazy loading, through out the application and also within each components if there are any components. Images can be lazy loaded. Videos can be lazy loaded.

Without seeing the content of app, cannot discuss more.